# Qual a forma correta de declarar a seguinte estrutura de classes e obter o respectivo comportamento do EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-pattern, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-6

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de classes:

```cs
public class Revenda
{
    [InverseProperty("Revenda")]
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioRevenda> Usuarios { get; set; }
}

public class Empresa
{
    [InverseProperty("Empresa")]
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioEmpresa> Usuarios { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente
{
    [InverseProperty("Cliente")]
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioCliente> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

Omiti algumas propriedades para não ficar muito extenso.

A estrutura consiste em Revendas que contém **Empresas** e essas contém seus clientes. **Empresas** são clientes de **Revendas** ficou sendo chamado assim.

Todavia o que estou demonstrando na estrutura é que pela classe `Revenda` tem a lista de Usuários cadastrados para a `Revenda`, na `Empresa` tem a lista de Usuários dela e no `Cliente` o mesmo, a lista de usuários dele.

Logo, em seguida tenho:

```cs
public class Usuario : IdentityUser {
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Revenda")]
    public virtual int RevendaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Revenda Revenda { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Empresa")]
    public virtual int? EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Cliente")]
    public virtual int? ClienteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Demais perfís de usuário:

```cs
public class UsuarioRevenda : Usuario { 
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Revenda")]
    public override int RevendaId { get; set; }
    public override Revenda Revenda { get; set; }
}

public class UsuarioEmpresa : Usuario { 
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Empresa")]
    public override int? EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public override Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
}

public class UsuarioCliente : Usuario { 
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Cliente")]
    public override int? ClienteId { get; set; }
    public override Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Aqui também foi omitido algumas propriedades de cada classe, como por exemplo, no `UsuarioRevenda` que tem uma propriedade de navegação das **Empresas** que ele possui acesso.

Via `Migrations`, logo no comando `Add-Migration`, estou recebendo uma mensagem dizendo que, `Revenda`, por exemplo, não pode ter uma propriedade do tipo `ICollection<UsuarioRevenda>`, por causa do atributo `InverseProperty` que aponta para uma propriedade originalmente declarada na classe `Usuario`, a propriedade `Revenda`.

A mensagem é a seguinte:

> Revenda: FromRole: NavigationProperty 'Revenda' is not valid. Type 'UsuarioRevenda' of FromRole 'Revenda_Usuarios_Target' in AssociationType 'Revenda_Usuarios' must exactly match with the type 'Usuario' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.

Todas as classes de usuários estão ligadas na mesma tabela do banco de dados, sendo então discrimiadas pelo campo ***Discriminator***, automaticamente, pelo **EntityFramework**.

Qual a forma correta de se declarar esse tipo de estrutura para o **EntityFramework** e usando **ASP.Net Identity**?

Comment: Acho desnecessário usar `InverseProperty`. Essa decoração é boa de fazer quando os nomes das classes são diferentes por algum motivo particular, o que não é o caso. Já experimentou tirar o atributo e executar o procedimento de migração?

Comment: Ele cria por uma limitação de comportamento do Entity Framework (acho que dei outra resposta pra uma pergunta sua a respeito).

Answer (score 1):

Como o comentário do companheiro Cigano, a atribuição do atributo *`InverseProperty`*

> "é boa de fazer quando os nomes das classes são diferentes por algum motivo particular, o que não é o caso."

Bastou remover o atributo das classes `Revenda`, `Empresa` e `Cliente`, nos métodos referênte ao erro retornado pelo ***EntityFramework***, que o problema foi resolvido.

Ou seja:

```cs
public class Revenda {
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioRevenda> Usuarios { get; set; }
}

public class Empresa {
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioEmpresa> Usuarios { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente {
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioCliente> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```